# Excel VBA If statement mistakenly triggering

Tags: vba, excel

OK, I have an If statement that shouldn't be triggering, but it is. Here's the current set-up:

```
If HP.Value > Range("HPMax").Value Then
    MsgBox (HP.Value & "/" & Range("HPMax").Value)
    HP.Value = Range("HPMax").Value
    MsgBox (HP.Value & "/" & Range("HPMax").Value)
 End If
```

I have the Message Boxes in to show me that it is indeed happening. currently HP is at 29, and HPMax is at 60.

Comment: Well, I found a work-around by adding another box to the userform showing the HPMax, but I'm still really curious why it was doing this and if anyone knows how to fix it

Answer (score 10):

You're not casting the textbox value to a number. Assuming you're comparing integer values, change your comparison to:

```
If IsNumeric(HP.Value) Then
    If Int(HP.Value) > Range("HPMax").Value Then
```

If the decimal place is important, use a Double:

```
If IsNumeric(HP.Value) Then
    If CDbl(HP.Value) > Range("HPMax").Value Then
```

**EDIT** In response to your comment:

The VBA equality (`=`, `<>`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`, `<`), addition (`+`) and concatenation (`&`) operators behave differently when **both** operands are `String` types, and when one or both operands is a numeric type.

```
'equality operators do string comparisons if both operands are strings, regardless of whether they're numeric
Debug.Print "25" < "200" 'Prints False
Debug.Print 25 < "200"   'Prints True
Debug.Print "25" < 200   'Prints True
Debug.Print 25 < 200     'Prints True

Debug.Print "25" > "200" 'Prints True
Debug.Print 25 > "200"   'Prints False
Debug.Print "25" > 200   'Prints False
Debug.Print 25 > 200     'Prints False

'+ concatenates if both items are strings, regardless of whether they're numeric
Debug.Print "25" + "200" 'Prints 25200
Debug.Print 25 + "200"   'Prints 225
Debug.Print "25" + 200   'Prints 225
Debug.Print 25 + 200     'Prints 225

'- always casts both operands to numbers, and if either is non numeric, throws a Type Mismatch error
Debug.Print "25" - "200" 'Prints -175
Debug.Print 25 - "200"   'Prints -175
Debug.Print "25" - 200   'Prints -175
Debug.Print 25 - 200     'Prints -175

'& Always concatenates
Debug.Print "25" & "200" 'Prints 25200
Debug.Print 25 & "200"   'Prints 25200
Debug.Print "25" & 200   'Prints 25200
Debug.Print 25 & 200     'Prints 25200
```

You might have code like this, that works **most** of the time

```
Dim x As String
x = "1"
Debug.Print x < "80", Int(x) < "80"  'Prints True True
```

But if `x` starts with `"9"`, you have a **bug**

```
x = "9"
Debug.Print x < "80", Int(x) < "80"  'Prints False True
```

Comment: Hmm, I have other things in various spots throughout my project that are almost exactly the same, however, and they all work. 
I dunno, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to urgently check the rest of your project. See my edit.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I understand now. Thanks! I have been going through the rest of my project, just to make sure everything else is done and working as much as anything else, and I haven't found this issue elsewhere